# My css stylesheets are not being routed correctly using node/express

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, routes

I am running into an issue with the routing of my CSS files for one specific page.
I am getting a 404 not found according to my morgan logger:

here is my router:

```
// @desc    Show new accomplishment page
// @route   GET /accomplishments
router.get("/", ensureAuth, accomplishmentsController.getAccomplishments)
router.get("/newAccomplishment", ensureAuth, accomplishmentsController.getNewAccomplishment)
router.post("/newAccomplishment", ensureAuth, accomplishmentsController.newAccomplishment)
```

here is my link inside the ejs file that routes to the newAccomplishment page when clicked:

```
  <section id="headerInfo">
    <h1 id="topicHeading">Celebrate Your Success With Others</h1>
    <h2> Add an Accomplishment <a href="/accomplishments/newAccomplishment"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i></a></h2>
  </section>
```

when clicking on that link it routes to the correct page but my CSS styles are not showing. Here is what it's showing in the morgan logs:
[image]

/accomplishments is getting added to my route to get the CSS files. It is supposed to just be /css/utilities.css
/css/style.css

any ideas on why this is getting added to my routes for my style sheet?

Comment: Show how you link css, and how do you serve css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When linking to the CSS, make sure the URL starts with `/` so it has an absolute path instead of being relative to the path of the HTML document as it is now.